# message.author.hasPermission is not a function in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

When I try to use the kick command, it says `TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function`. I want it to not work if you don't have the permission `KICK_MEMBERS`.
This is my code that is returning the error:

```js
if (!message.author.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) class, which has no `.hasPermission` method.

I think you are looking for [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), which returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

---

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return;
```